# Audio of Tenach for children of any age (online)

Tags: internet, navi-prophets, hearing

Please help me find online audio of the Tenach (in English, Russian or Hebrew translation) (spesificly neviim) for children of any age

Comment: You mean a recording of someone reading it? With Trop? Without? Do you want a specific pronunciation scheme?

Comment: @DoubleAA more interested in english translation, (for them to listen to it an not jus audio books) (thank you I will right it in)

Answer (score 1):

Try [this audio book version (it is not free):](https://jps.org/jps-audio-bible/) **JPS TANAKH: The Jewish Bible.**

Comment: @hazoriz not at all