# Would anyone be able to suggest a Torah in audio book format?

Tags: torah-study, chinuch-education

This may or may not be an unsual request.

I was interested in finding an **audiobook format** of the Torah. Basically just the Torah (from beginning to end) being read by a narrator. Would anyone be able to point me in the direction of something like this?

Edit:

It can be in a single file or broken down into parts. I'm extremely fluid in whatever you provide.

My Hebrew still isn't perfect so if you happen to know of english translations, that would be preferred.

Comment: http://www.chabad.org/multimedia/media_cdo/aid/982057/jewish/Torah-Reading-Recordings.htm These are the readings in Hebrew - however the readings, even all of them, do not make up the entire Torah since they are segments of each parsha

Comment: https://jps.org/jps-audio-bible/ Here's the entire Tanach in audio form!

Comment: dup? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/76023

Comment: http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/ptmp3prq.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an iPhone, I would recommend Zev Clementson's [HebrewBible](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hebrewbible/id310104088?mt=8). In addition to having a fully functional concordance, with links to BDB, you can also choose to play a recording of the text, either chapter by chapter or parshah by parshah (in the case of Torah). The person reading does so in a very clear, Sephardi pronunciation, and announces at the beginning of every chapter the chapter and book from which he is reading. (The Aramaic sections are read by somebody else: a man with a very strong North American accent. I don't know the identity of either person.)

**Addendum**: The same audio recordings can also be accessed on [this site](https://listen.talkingbibles.org/en/language/heb). If you go to their home page ([here](https://listen.talkingbibles.org/en)), you can access recordings of Tanakh in various other languages as well. The English translation that they offer is that of the King James Version.